# Class function with parameter of same type as class

Tags: c++, function, class, parameters, self-reference

I am trying to write a chess engine in C++. I have a class `gameState` which stores the positions, types, and colors of the pieces, and has several functions to determine relevant information about the board, such as whether a given king is in check. It also has the function `makeCopyOf(gameState g)`, which copies the parameter’s data to its own.

I am trying to write a function in `gameState` which tests for checkmate, and in order to do this I would like to copy its data into another temporary object of the same type. Is there a way to pass `gameState` as a parameter to one of its own functions? Some thing like `this` in JavaScript?

Comment: C++ has a `this` member for *all* classes - but it is a *pointer* to the object, so you have to deference it for the object itself (use `*this`). However, using that in a class copy function could present some problems. Show us (some of) your code if you want a more detailed answer!

Comment: Showing code is much easier to understand. Explaining code in words is hard. This question is very unclear.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking to write a [Copy Constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

This is similar to a constructor or initializer but takes the same class in as a parameter and creates a new class. For example, yours might look something like this:

```
class GameState {
  public:
    GameState(const GameState& g) {
      game_state_var_1 = g.game_state_var_1;
      game_state_var_2 = g.game_state_var_2;

      // ...
  }
};
```

Then in practice you would use it like this:

```
GameState g = GameState();
GameState duplicate_g = GameState(g);
```

It's also worth noting that if you're coming from a JavaScript background it's really important to know that JavaScript is a unique language. Neither functional nor object oriented, but pretending to be both. Before you write a new function in your class, take a moment to see if C++ supports overriding operations to do it first.

For example, you described your `makeCopyOf(gameState g)` function that you wrote for your `GameState` class. But a more idiomatic C++ approach would be to override the = operator like this:

```
class GameState {
  public:
    const GameState& operator=(const GameState& g) {
      game_state_var_1 = g.game_state_var_1;
      game_state_var_2 = g.game_state_var_2;

      // ....
      return *this;
    }
};
```

Which means you could just use an assignment operator to set the values of your `GameState` object to that of another `GameState` object, like this:

```
GameState g1 = GameState(1);
GameState g2 = GameState(2);

g1 = g2;
// g1 now has the same data as g2
```

Hope this helps, without any code its hard to directly answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

I realized almost immediately after posting that I could just use function overloading to define another makeCopyOf() without any parameters. This appears to have solved my problem.